# How to use .htaccess to redirect a url which has a # character

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've been looking at this for a couple of days, even had the IT guys at work try and figure it out but we didn't get very far.

I have a url `my.website.com/index.php#!lightBox[gallery]/0/` which I want to redirect to just my.website.com. I can do it fine with just the index.php, but it's the extra parts that aren't working. I've tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://my.website.com/index.php#!lightBox[gallery]/0/? [R=301,L]
```

and cpanel generated the following redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my.website.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.my.website.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/my\.website\.com\/\#\!lightBox\[gallery\]\/0\/" [R=301,L]
```

Both output `my.website.com/%23!lightBox[gallery]/0/` as the url - as you can see the hash isn't being processed.

If anyone has any ideas I'd love to hear!

Thanks :)

Comment: Seems like CPanel is incorrectly escaping the second `RewriteRule` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?my\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://my.website.com/index.php#!lightBox[gallery]/0/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

You do need to escape dot `.` in RewriteCond but don't need to escape any special characters on RHS. Importantly you need to have flag `NE` to not to escape the resulting URI.

Comment: Thank you! It kept the url intact but ended up giving an error - "Too many redirects occurred trying to open “http://my.website.com/#!lightBox[gallery]/0/”. This might occur if you open a page that is redirected to open another page which then is redirected to open the original page." in safari and firefox gave a similar error as well. I deleted everything else in my .htaccess to see if something was conflicting but the same thing happened again.

Comment: Actually, added in index.php so that  

    RewriteRule ^/?$ http://my.website.com/index.php#!lightBox[gallery]/0/ [R=301,L,NE]  


and it's working. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome, I updated my answer to reflect `index.php` as well.